# Why my output shows shows every choice in the calculator?

Tags: c++

I'm doing a calculator in C++ (Visual Studio) that make you choose which operation you want between (Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication & Division) then you enter two numbers and get the answer. But when I run the program and I choose between the four choices and enter the two numbers the program shows me the answer in every choice. Here's the code, please tell me what I did wrong and what should I do to show the answer for the choice I made only.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int Q1Number, Num1, Num2, Answer;
    cout << "Welcome!" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Write the number to begin:" << endl;
    cout << " 1- Addition " << endl;
    cout << " 2- Subtraction " << endl;
    cout << " 3- Multiplication " << endl;
    cout << " 4- Division " << endl;
    cin >> Q1Number;
    cout << "Enter The first number";
    cin >> Num1;
    cout << "Enter The second number";
    cin >> Num2;



    if (Q1Number = 1)

        Answer = Num1 + Num2;

    cout << " Answer is : " << Answer << endl;

    if (Q1Number = 2);

        Answer = Num1 - Num2;

    cout << " Answer is : " << Answer << endl;

     if (Q1Number = 2);

        Answer = Num1 * Num2;

        cout << " Answer is : " << Answer << endl;  

    if (Q1Number = 2);

            Answer = Num1 / Num2;

        cout << " Answer is : " << Answer << endl;



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should cnahge `=` to `==` in your `if` statements.

Moreover, you should check `Num2 != 0` in case you are going to divide.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int Q1Number, Num1, Num2;
int Answer = 0;
cout << "Welcome!" << endl;
cout << "" << endl;
cout << "Write the number to begin:" << endl;
cout << " 1- Addition " << endl;
cout << " 2- Subtraction " << endl;
cout << " 3- Multiplication " << endl;
cout << " 4- Division " << endl;
cin >> Q1Number;
cout << "Enter The first number";
cin >> Num1;
cout << "Enter The second number";
cin >> Num2;
if (Num2 == 0 && Q1Number == 4)
    {
        cout << "Num2 is 0. We don't divide by zero" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

if (Q1Number == 1)
{
    Answer = Num1 + Num2;

    cout << " Answer is : " << Answer << endl;
}

if (Q1Number == 2)
{
    Answer = Num1 - Num2;

    cout << " Answer is : " << Answer << endl;
}

if (Q1Number == 3)
{
    Answer = Num1 * Num2;

    cout << " Answer is : " << Answer << endl;  
}

if (Q1Number == 4)
{
    Answer = Num1 / Num2;

    cout << " Answer is : " << Answer << endl;
}
return 0;
```

Also it might be better to use `switch(Q1Number)` instead of using `if` statements.

 With `switch` it should looks like this:

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

    int Q1Number, Num1, Num2, Answer;
    cout << "Welcome!" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Write the number to begin:" << endl;
    cout << " 1- Addition " << endl;
    cout << " 2- Subtraction " << endl;
    cout << " 3- Multiplication " << endl;
    cout << " 4- Division " << endl;
    cin >> Q1Number;
    cout << "Enter The first number";
    cin >> Num1;
    cout << "Enter The second number";
    cin >> Num2;

    if (Num2 == 0 && Q1Number == 4)
    {
        cout << "Num2 is 0. We don't divide by zero" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    switch(Q1Number)
    {
        case 1:
            Answer = Num1 + Num2;
            break;
        case 2:
            Answer = Num1 - Num2;
            break;
        case 3:
            Answer = Num1*Num2;
            break;
        case 4:
            Answer = Num1/Num2;
            break;
        default: 
            cout << " Wrong option selected " << endl
            break;
    }

    cout << " Answer is : " << Answer << endl

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: its probably better just to put `cout << " Answer is : " << Answer << endl;` once at the end than in each if block, also missing closing curly at end

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your `if` statements. You need to use `==` instead of `=` . With `=` , you are assigning values, and that is the problem.

So, change

```
if (Q1Number = 1)
```

to

```
if (Q1Number == 1)
```

and subsequently make the same edit to all of your `if` statements.

When it is `=`, the operator returns the value it assigns, so in your case, the values assigned are 1 and 2, which result to `true` and hence, the condition in the `if` statement is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually assigning instead of testing (operator = is different of operator ==)

Answer (score 1):

`if(a = b)` means assign `b` to `a`, then test if the result evaluates to `true`. Whenever `b` is non-zero, this will be the case. To test for equality, you need to use the `==` operator, `if(a == b)`